# How to validate Multiple Ids in the Webservice Method

Tags: c#, web-services

hai Friends

I am using this coding for validating the emailID online through webservice method.i will get a input a from a textboa and the click the button.but it is validating the emailId only one at a time.how to vaildate multiple EmaiIDs and validate and return the values.or how to split the ids and validate let me know.

The webservice link is http://www.webservicex.net/ValidateEmail.asmx?wsdl

So far my coding is

```
protected void ValidateEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateEmail.ValidateEmailSoapClient EmailClient = new ValidateEmail.ValidateEmailSoapClient("ValidateEmailSoap12");
    bool bval = System.Convert.ToBoolean(EmailClient.IsValidEmail(txtvalidateEmail.Text));
    Response.Write("Email Address is " + bval.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you've posted doesn't open here but I will try to answer your question. If the web service has another method that allows you to pass multiple email addresses then you can use this method. If not, you will need to call the web service for each email you are trying to validate which of course might not be very efficient.

Comment: i need the result the webservice i provide will not validate multiple ids if there is any other webservice to validate the emailids pls let me know. or how to split the emailid and split the values and validate.